# It is possible to add event listener for 'error' event to HTMLImageElement?

Tags: javascript

I need to add 'error' event listener for all images.
But it should be added using window.HTMLImageElement (or via window.HTMLImageElement.constructor, window.HTMLImageElement.prototype.constructor, etc.)

Comment: Neither. Event handlers are added with `addEventListener`.

Comment: No those cannot be used for creating global image error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [the `error` event doesn't bubble](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlimageelement), so you can't use a delegated handler. From that link (the last "Otherwise" on Step 14):

> Either the image data is corrupted in some fatal way such that the image dimensions cannot be obtained, or the image data is not in a supported file format; the user agent must set the `img` element to the broken state, abort the fetching algorithm, discarding any pending tasks generated by that algorithm, and then queue a task to first [fire a simple event](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `error` at the `img` element and then fire a simple event named `loadend` at the `img` element.

Where "fire a simple event" says:

> Firing a simple event named `e` means that a trusted event with the name `e`, which **does not bubble** (except where otherwise stated) and is not cancelable (except where otherwise stated), and which uses the Event interface, must be created and dispatched at the given target.

*(my emphasis)*

Instead, you have to hook a handler up to each and every image on the page (you can look them up with `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll`), being careful to check whether the image is already complete (in which case the event may have already been fired).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the `HTMLImageElement.prototype` to achieve what you need to do.

However, you can try using `addEventListener` to check for image errors.

```
window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
    if ( e.target && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img' ) {
      console.log('image error');
    }
}, true);
```

Sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzp0jfy4/)

In general I would say it is a bad idea to change the prototype of any native objects, as it may lead to strange side effects as the code base grows.